# VPN PPTPD with MPPE Support for Debian or Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, debian, vpn, pptp

Having an unencrypted vpn connection from a windows client to linux is pretty easy by using pptpd. When I was looking for an solution for encrypted (per MPPE) connection, I found a lot of information about patching the kernel etc. - so it definitly works after some work. But all these information is pretty old (2005-2006).

Is it the same solution nowadays? I am not asking for a complete instruction (only if it's short) - I am more asking for a link to the right solution.

Comment: *"Having an unencrypted vpn connection..."* - I don't believe there is such a thing. The VPN standards don't have the equivalent to TLS's `eNULL`. VPN does not even allow opportunistic encryption or better-than-nothing encryption. Everything is encrypted, and you need to be pre-provisioned.

Comment: PPTP, even with MPPE, was broken and obsolete many years before this question was posted. There's no point to using it now.

Answer (score 1):

Even with encryption, the security of PPTP is pretty weak:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-to-Point_Tunneling_Protocol#Security

That's why PPTP seems to be getting deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell you no longer need to do any patching (since Linux 2.6.16/Debian 4 at least). MPPE is now included as a kernel module (ppp_mppe.ko). You can check for it like this:

```
find /lib/modules/`uname -r` -name 'ppp_mppe.ko'
```

Also check your /etc/ppp/options.pptp for related directives like `require-mppe-12`.

A sure way to confirm its use is to connect to your server and then check if the module is loaded:

`lsmod | grep -i mppe`

Finally, a Debian-oriented link: http://pptpclient.sourceforge.net/howto-debian.phtml

Answer (score 0):

You could use accel-ppp if you have 2.6.37 or later linux kernel,  starting from 2.6.37 pptp is included to mainline kernel so there is no need to apply any patches. You can find more info on http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/accel-ppp/